# How to use Arel methods like `coalesce` outside Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I want to generate a partial query outside Active Record models, e.g.

```
class Foo
  def to_arel
    coalesce(1, 2)
  end
end
```

I could go via some existing model, but that's inelegant:

```
Item.arel_table.coalesce(1, 2).to_sql # => "COALESCE(1, 2)"
```

What's a better way?

(This project is currently on Rails 6.1, but I'm interested in solutions for newer versions as well.)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
class Foo
  def to_arel
    arel.coalesce(1, 2)
  end

  private

  def arel
    @arel ||= Class.new.extend(Arel::FactoryMethods)
  end
end
```

(I could also `include Arel::FactoryMethods` in `Foo` directly, but that seems messy to me.)

`Foo.new.to_arel` returns an `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction` instance. Calling `to_sql` will only work if there is a DB connection, as I noticed when I tried doing it in a Rails-less test. That's because e.g. MySQL or Postgres connections might generate different SQL.

Comment: If you don't mind adding AR as a dependency you can generate the SQL without using all of rails (provided you have a database to connect to). That database can be empty, meaning it does not need tables or data to generate queries, you just need something for the adapter to hold on to.